# could not call function when create PDF in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using `react-native-html-to-pdf` to create a pdf file it's work fine

but in my case, I have an array and I want to iterate them to append it to HTML,

so I make a function that iterates items and returns HTML tags when I log these items I can see it inside my console logs 
But when I open the PDF file generated I just see undefined! although it's logged well

```
state =  {
     toolsUsed: [
      {
        name: 'N-1',
        price: 10,
        count: 3,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 150).toString(),
      },
      {
        name: 'N-2',
        price: 5,
        count: 3,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 150).toString(),
      },
      {
        name: 'N-3',
        price: 10,
        count: 7,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 150).toString(),
      },
    ],
}
```

**Function**

```
printTool = () => {
    this.state.toolsUsed.map(({name, price, count, id}) => {
      console.log('name', name); // it log successful
      console.log('price', price);// it log successful
      console.log('count', count);// it log successful
      return (
        <>
          <p key={id} style="text-align:right;padding:10px;">
            name: ${name}
          </p>
          <p key={id} style="text-align:right;padding:10px">
            count: ${count}
          </p>
          <p key={id} style="text-align:right;padding:10px">
            price: ${price}
          </p>
        </>
      );
    });
  };
```

**create PDF File**

```
  async createPDF() {
     let options = {
      //Content to print in PDF file
      html: `<h1 style="text-align: center;">
               Bill
             </h1>
            <div>
              ${this.printTool()} // I got undefined in PDF
            </div>`,

      fileName: `Bill${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`,
      directory: 'Downloads',
    };

   let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
   this.setState({filePath: file.filePath}, () => alert(this.state.filePath));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **return** statement to `printTool()`

```
printTool = () => {
return this.state.toolsUsed.map(({name, price, count, id}) => {
  console.log('name', name); // it log successful
  console.log('price', price);// it log successful
  console.log('count', count);// it log successful
  return (
     '<p><p key={id} style="text-align:right;padding:10px;">name: '+name+'</p><p key={id} style="text-align:right;padding:10px">count: '+count+'</p><p key={id} style="text-align:right;padding:10px">price: '+price+'</p></p>'
  );
});
};
```

if you try to log the function `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.printTool()))`
The JSON will look like [json](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=aac147edfd0c486983b590681eb9cc83)

Then change it according to your pdf view

Comment: thanks for the response, I got `[Object Object]` in PDF

Comment: I solved my issue by return directly  the html like `return``<p>.......</p>`

Comment: i mean without `()`, but i have a Q why we write **return** `this.state.toolsUsed.map..`

Comment: @OliverD why we write return this.state.toolsUsed.map - because you have created the `<p>` elements using map function but you didn't return that elements to your function for pdf display. Anyway if my answer help to solve the problem, accept and upvote to my answer